# how to pass ForeignKey in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I used the flask to create a simple web application.
now in model's I have bar table which has the relationship with 2 other table.

```
    user_shipper_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user_shipper.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
user_receiver_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user_receiver.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
```

now on `user_shipper`, i have this:

```
        bars = relationship('bar',backref='shipper',lazy='dynamic')
```

an also in `user_receiver` table :

```
bars = relationship('bar',backref='receiver',lazy='dynamic')
```

now I have a problem here: 
in bar's table `init` function i have this :

```
    def __init__(self, origin, destination, tonage, load_date, unload_date, load_address, unload_adress, unload_type, packing, act_type, truck_type, payment_type):
    self.origin = origin
    self.destination = destination
    self.tonage = tonage
    self.load_date = load_date
    self.unload_date = unload_date
    self.load_adress = load_adress
    self.unload_type = unload_type
    self.unload_adress = unload_adress
    self.packing = packing
    self.act_type = act_type
    self.truck_type = truck_type
    self.payment_type = payment_type
```

now when i trying to insert into table with sqlalchemy its show error and say this :

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'receiver'
```

how can I pass the ForeignKey when I trying to insert ? should I define something in init function?

Comment: Well it looks like you're trying to do `Bar(receiver=whatever)` but you haven't defined `receiver` as a parameter in `Bar.__init__`. Can you post the rest of your code, especially the part where you do the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass both `user_receiver_id` and `user_shipper_id` on object initialization.

I have not tested this, but you may try to use this as an insight!

```
class UserShipper():
    ...
    bars = relationship('Bar', back_populates='shipper', lazy='dynamic')


class UserReceiver():
    ...
    bars = relationship('Bar', back_populates='receiver', lazy='dynamic')


class Bar():
    ...
    user_shipper_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user_shipper.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    shipper = relationship('UserShipper', back_populates='bars')

    user_receiver_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user_receiver.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    receiver = relationship('UserReceiver', back_populates='bars')

    def __init(self, ..., user_shipper_id, user_receiver_id):
        ...
        self.user_shipper_id = user_shipper_id
        self.user_receiver_id = user_receiver_id
```